# Client side validation of date time passes when not entered but model has it as required

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I am using MVC 5 with the following model:

```
public class PassengerItem
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Class constructor
    /// </summary>
    public PassengerItem()
    {
        DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}

public class BookingProcessViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Class constructor
    /// </summary>
    public BookingProcessViewModel()
    {
        ErrorMessages = new OzCpResultErrors();
        Passengers = new List<PassengerItem>();

        //Populate with 4 passengers. We show/hide these in the view. Currently we only allow a max of 4 pax to be booked at a time
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Passengers.Add(new PassengerItem());
        }
    }
}
```

and in my razor view (using [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com) and [jQuery UI Helpers](http://jqueryuihelpers.apphb.com/)) I have:

```
@f.FormGroup().CustomControls(@Html.JQueryUI().DatepickerFor(m => m.Passengers[i].DateOfBirth, new { @class = "form-control"}).ChangeYear(true).ChangeMonth(true).ConstrainInput(true).MaxDate(DateTime.Today).DefaultDate(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).CustomLabel("Date Of Birth").ShowRequiredStar(true)
```

which generates the following HTML:

```
<div class=" form-group"><label class="control-label" for="">Date Of Birth<span aria-required="true" class="required">*</span> </label><input class="form-control hasDatepicker" data-jqui-dpicker-changemonth="True" data-jqui-dpicker-changeyear="True" data-jqui-dpicker-constraininput="True" data-jqui-dpicker-dateformat="dd/mm/yy" data-jqui-dpicker-defaultdate="01/01/1970" data-jqui-dpicker-maxdate="21/09/2015" data-jqui-type="datepicker" id="Passengers_0__DateOfBirth" name="Passengers[0].DateOfBirth" value="01/01/1970" type="text"></div>
```

I hook up the submit function so that I can display a dialog for confirmation purposes.

```
 //Hook the submit functionality for the form
 $(formJQuerySelector).submit(function(aArgs) {
      aArgs.preventDefault();

     //Validate the fields with MVC validation.
     if ($(this).valid()) {
         $(confirmDialogJquerySelector).dialog('open');
     }
  });
```

Now if i clear the content of the date input and attempt to submit the form I would expect it to fail as it is a required field, non nullable. However validation passes without issue.

Also if I enter a date greater than today then validation also passes.

So clearly the validation for this field is not working. I cannot work out if it is a problem with jQuery, unobtrusive validation or both.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: The rendered html you have shown does not include any of the `data-val` attributes required for client side validation. Could be because client side validation is disabled or the control is no inside a form element

Comment: Hmmm... Well spotted. Client side validation is not disabled as I have other controls that are being validated (just not included for brevity) and it is inside a form element. I suspect this is a combination of the MVC Razor helpers.